# Finding if this series converges $\sum \frac{1}{n\ln(n)+\sqrt{\ln^3(n)}}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Here's how I solved it:

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\le \frac{1}{\ln(n)} \rightarrow\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^n}}\le\frac{1}{\ln(n^n)}$$

And so, $\frac{1}{\ln(n^n)+\sqrt{\ln^3(n)}} \ge \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^n}}$

I can prove that $\sum \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^n}}$ diverges because $\lim \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^n}} \neq 0$. Thus the given series diverges as it is greater than $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^n}}$. Is this correct?

Comment: You're wrong: $\frac1{\sqrt{n^n}}$ tends to $0$.

Comment: Hint for one approach: when $a,b>0$,$$\frac1{a+b} \ge \frac1{2\max\{a,b\}} = \min\bigg\{ \frac1{2a},\frac1{2b}\bigg\}.$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not correct --
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} n^n=\infty,$$
which means that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^n}}=0.$$
In fact, since $\frac{1}{n\ln n}\to 0$, it would be impossible to show that the sum diverges by comparison to a sum of terms where the terms don't converge to $0$, so something had to be wrong.

For a hint on how to solve the problem, consider limit comparison with
$$\sum \frac{1}{n\ln n}$$
to get rid of the annoying term, and then try to use the integral test or Cauchy condensation, whichever you're more familiar with.

Comment: I'm having a brain freeze, how do I find if $\frac{1}{n\ln(n)}$ converges or diverges?

Comment: @SilenceOnTheWire I mentioned two convergence tests -- see if you can get either of them to work.

Comment: Solved it, thanks. Also solved a couple more I was stuck on using this

Answer (score 1):

It does diverge, but not for the reason you cite.

Here is a short argument, based on asymptotic analysis:
$$\frac{\sqrt{\ln^3n}}{n\ln n}=\frac{\sqrt{\ln n}}{n}\xrightarrow[\:n\to\infty\:]{}0,$$
so that $\;n\ln(n)+\sqrt{\ln^3(n)}\sim_\infty n\ln n$ and ultimately
$$\frac{1}{n\ln(n)+\sqrt{\ln^3(n)}}\sim_\infty\frac{1}{n\ln n},$$
which is a divergent *Bertrand's series* (use, e.g. the integral test).

Comment: Quick question: when solving limits with polynomials you can just take the term with biggest power and ignore the others (if the limit is to infinity). Can you do that too if the powers aren't integers? It looks to me that's what you did, just making sure

Comment: Yes (provided the exponents are constants). Formally, it means the function is asymptotically equivalent to its leading term.

Comment: Isn't 3/2 greater than 1 then in this case (why does it tend to $n\ln n$)?

Comment: I had messed up between the numerator and denominator (computing and typing directly on screen). I've fixed it. B.t.w., equivalence doesn't mean it tends to $n\ln n$,  it only means their ratio tends to $1$.